# Derivative of determinant and Mahalanobis distance w.r.t matrix elements

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant

I have the following two functions of a symmetric $k\times k$ positive-definite covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}s_{11} & \cdots & s_{1k}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ s_{k1} & \cdots & s_{kk}\end{pmatrix}$:

$$f_1(\boldsymbol\Sigma) = \ln |\boldsymbol\Sigma|$$
$$f_2(\boldsymbol\Sigma) = -\frac12(\textbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\textbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu).$$

**My question is:** what is the derivatives of these two functions w.r.t. matrix elements $s_{ij}$? That is, how to calculate:

$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial s_{ij}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial s_{ij}}?$$

I'd be happy also simply to an answer which redirects to a book/source where these questions are addressed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of typing, define the variables
$$w=(x-\mu),\qquad S=\Sigma$$
We'll also need the following results
for an arbitrary matrix ($A$) and function ($f$)
$$\eqalign{
dA^{-1} &= -A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1} \\
d\,{\rm Tr}\Big(f(A)\Big)
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(df(A)\Big)
  = {\rm Tr}\Big(f'(A)\cdot dA\Big) \\
\log\Big(\det(A)\Big) &= {\rm Tr}\Big(\log(A)\Big) + 2n\pi i\\
}$$
Applying this to the first function
$$\eqalign{
 f_1 &= \log\Big(\det(S)\Big) \\
df_1 &= d\log\Big(\det(S)\Big) \\
  &= d\,{\rm Tr}\Big(\log(S)\Big) \\
  &= {\rm Tr}\Big(S^{-1}\,dS\Big) \\
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial S} &= S^{-1}
 \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial s_{ij}} &= \big(S^{-1}\big)_{ij} \\
}$$
and to the second function
$$\eqalign{
 f_2 &= -\tfrac 12 w^TS^{-1}w \\
df_2 &= -\tfrac 12 w^T\color{red}{dS^{-1}}w \\
 &= +\tfrac 12 w^T\color{red}{S^{-1}dS\,S^{-1}}w \\
 &= \tfrac 12\,{\rm Tr}\Big(S^{-1}ww^TS^{-1}dS\Big) \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial S}
  &= \tfrac 12 S^{-1}ww^TS^{-1}
  \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial s_{ij}}
  &= \tfrac 12\big(S^{-1}ww^TS^{-1}\big)_{ij} \\
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg thank you very much for your help! Could you elaborate a bit more what e.g. $dA$ means? The differential w.r.t to all entries in the matrix?

Comment: Also, any recommendation for books/sources related to matrix differentiation where I could find these and similar results? Thank you!

Comment: Should I treat $dA$ as a constant or a matrix? I'm not used to matrix differentiation but for example it wasn't clear to me why from $df_1 = Tr\left(S^{-1}dS\right)$ it follows that $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial S} = S^{-1}$? Is $dS$ a constant scalar here? or a constant matrix?

Comment: Don't worry about my last question, I checked it already :) see it now.

Comment: @jjepsuomi The symbol $dA$ is the differential of the matrx $A$ -- here is a [good primer](https://bridge.math.oregonstate.edu/papers/differentials.pdf) on the concept. The standard textbook for this entire field is [_Matrix Differential Calculus_](https://books.google.com/books/about/Matrix_Differential_Calculus_with_Applic.html?id=8sOKDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description) by Magnus and Neudecker (wherein Part 3 is devoted to differentials).

Comment: ...and in older editions of Magnus and Neudecker, differentials are covered in Chapter 13.

Comment: perfect, thank you!